# Converting string columns to numeric values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns as string but storing only numeric values.
I want to take sum of these two columns and display it as third column using Oracle SQL.

Can someone help me with this?

Note: I can not use PL/SQL for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of possible solutions:

```
select tax, amount, 
    case when tax is not null and amount is not null 
          and replace(translate( tax,    '123456789', '000000000' ), '0', '') is null
          and replace(translate( amount, '123456789', '000000000' ), '0', '') is null
        then to_number(tax)+to_number(amount) 
        else 0
    end summed 
  from teststr
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c3e8/1)</sup>

You can read [this article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1794145000346577404) 
about several other methods including regular expressions and PLSQL function which may be useful if your data contains values like `'23.96'`.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you actually provided a bit more details about your table, columns, what the data looks like.  But assuming a table with 2 `varchar2` columns that contains numeric data, you can do this:

```
SELECT col1, col2,
       to_number(col1) + to_number(col2) as sum_of_cols
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: create table TESTSTR
(
"TAX" VARCHAR2(5) , 
 "AMOUNT" VARCHAR2(5)
 
);

Comment: this is data  
TAX          null 12     22 ab\n
amount     12   null   12 10

Comment: I want to add both the columns
it should add if it gets numeric values else it should make them zero and do the calculations on encountering any nu;ll/string value

Comment: Can you try moving these extra explanations into the body of your question?  That way others will see them as well.  And you can format the data better that way.  With the comments, I am having a hard time understanding the format of the data.  Can you have decimals in there, or only digits?  And why isn't it always numeric?  Why isn't your data consistent?  Why aren't you using proper data types? :(

Comment: So what I am understanding is that when your question said: "I have two columns as string but storing ***only*** numeric values", it sounds like this wasn't true at all.  Well, if you have a mixed bag of data types in the same column, and you want numeric conversion without getting an error, I don't know how to do that without PL/SQL.  Maybe you should consider cleaning up the data and using the proper data types for the columns in question.